# Presenting data in a SF Case externally

Tags: lightning, case, external

I'm looking for a way to present data in a Salesforce Case externally to a customer, without them having any login setup for our Salesforce.

There doesn't seem to be any native capability for this in Lightning that I can see, so I'm looking for advice on addons or external services that can do this.

Each account in SF has an Activation Case that we use to track their onboarding progress into our system. The data there is not particularly complex - mostly dates, dropdown statuses and a couple of text fields.

I'd like to be able to present this data externally to each account giving them live access to view the progress of their onboarding at any stage. Ideally I'm looking to be able to present it in a prettier and more user-friendly way with some conditional formatting:
e.g.
Big green ticks if all relevant fields are CONFIRMED or COMPLETED
or
If the TRAINING date is not confirmed 1 week before the GOLIVE date have some sort of red flagging on the page

Would love to have any advice on how to achieve this, Thanks.

Comment: Native capability for rendering a component outside of SF platform is [Lightning Out](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.234.0.lightning.meta/lightning/lightning_out.htm). Other options are covered in [Data Integration](https://architect.salesforce.com/design/decision-guides/data-integration)

Answer (score 1):

Technically, you'd be better off getting one of the authenticated portal licenses, such as [Customer Portal](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.users_license_types_customerportal.htm&type=5) licenses. They are pretty reasonably priced for what they offer, and you'd have native support for your customers to view their cases. You would probably want to do this even if you decide to go with the custom interface you describe. That said, if you want to provide unauthenticated read-only access, you could use an unauthenticated [Experience Cloud](https://www.salesforce.com/products/experience-cloud/overview/) template; they allow you to write your own components and expose them without any login required. You can also use [Sites](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.sites_overview.htm&language=en_US&r=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2F&type=5) to expose pages you write yourself.